# Faster alternative to using a cursor in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I have a cursor that iterates through every base table in a database. It inserts records into another table by executing a piece of dynamic SQL, but as of now it takes over 20 mins to execute.

```
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM <DB>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    #Dynamic SQL Query to insert data into each table in cursor#
```

I have done some research and found that using a CTE with a UNION expression will be much quicker but I'm not sure how to go about the conversion e.g how to loop over each table in the CTE.

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**: this is an example of the dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT @SQL = 'WITH CTE_DATES(DATE_VAL) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE_VAL
    FROM DATE_EVERY_DAY
    WHERE DATE_VAL <= GETDATE()
)
INSERT INTO COUNT_RECORDS_TABLE (DATE_VAL, TABLE_NAME, NUM_RECS_IMPORTED)
SELECT cd.DATE_VAL, ''' + @TableName + ''' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(CAST(tn.IMPORT_DATE AS DATE)) AS NUM_RECS_IMPORTED
FROM CTE_DATES AS cd LEFT JOIN ' + @TableName + ' AS tn 
ON CAST(tn.IMPORT_DATE AS DATE) = cd.DATE_VAL
GROUP BY cd.DATE_VAL'
```

Comment: AFAIK you don't really have much of a choice here, since you need dynamic SQL to select the target table for each query you want to run.  But, is performance here a big concern?  How often would you be running this code?

Comment: @AJennings1 . . . The issue is probably not the cursor (in this case) but the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Comment out only the line(s) that executes the DynamicSQL and the time it again.  That will tell you whether building the DynamicSQL is a bottleneck or not.

Comment: One solution would be to store the script you want to execute in a text file, then execute it using sqlcmd, the creation of the sql script can be done using sql joins, in most cases, but I need to know more details about your script to confirm

Comment: @GordonLinoff See edit

Comment: My SQL Query  is a method to count the number of records imported to each table every day between two dates, then save this count into another table. It seems the query is the problem here

Comment: What is `Date_Col` ? Is it a `datetime` or string? is it covered by an index? If it's a string, or is not covered by an index, each query will have to scan the entire table, causing a big delay

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Date_Col is a datetime. i am casting it to a normal short date to join with another set of distinct dates from a CTE

Comment: @AJennings1 is it indexed though? What does the CTE do? Does the query take advantage of the indexes or does it fall back to a full table scan? Without the actual queries and execution plans people can't really help

Comment: @AJennings1 perhaps you could use [Change Tracking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to get the changed rows since the last update. Change tracking is meant to return [at least the row key and change reason](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#using-the-change-tracking-functions-to-obtain-changes) (ie Insert, Update, Delete) but you could use it to only get the count of changed rows since the last check

Comment: Perhaps a better approach is to put your counting into your import logic.

Comment: Don,t use DISTINCT in your queries..It,s not optimize .

Comment: The query you've posted as the dynamic query should raise an error. Please [edit] your question with a more realistic code (and also, it would help if you could show the process inside the cursor loop.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions everyone. Seems that the cursor is the only realistic way of achieving this functionality, even though it takes 20 mins :)

Comment: EDIT: I have included the SQL code structure

Comment: You could add triggers on the table, on insert, so it updates your 'count' table (+1 on current date).

Comment: Why do you need the join? Just cast IMPORT_DATE to date and group by that. and filter directly on IMPORT_DATE using GETDATE(). Your problem is not the cursor.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I need to join to a specific date range. The left join is in place so that if records were not imported on a day in the CTE, then the count would return '0', which is necessary for this project

Comment: @AJennings1 Thats valid, but then do it afterwards, finding the gaps, which are probably few instead of what could be a non indexed join on millions of rows? Or like another person said, do it in your import code if possible. Or turn the problem around, why do it for every day? why not once a day and store the history?

Answer (score 1):

I would try using sys.sp_MSForeachTable. This is about as quick as it gets, and the ? character is the table name in [schema].[tablename] format. Obvously you can do a bit of text replacement if you just need the table name. The direct substitution means you don't need to mess with the CTE, and if there is an index on the DATE_EVERY_DAY.DATE_VAL column, this query may be able to leverage it.

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachtable 
'INSERT INTO COUNT_RECORDS_TABLE (DATE_VAL, TABLE_NAME, NUM_RECS_IMPORED)
SELECT 
    cd.DATE_VAL,
    ''?'' AS TABLE_NAME, 
    COUNT(tn.IMPORT_DATE) AS NUM_RECS_IMPORTED 
FROM 
    DATE_EVERY_DAY AS cd
    LEFT JOIN 
    ? AS tn ON 
        CAST(tn.IMPORT_DATE AS DATE)=cd.DATE_VAL
WHERE
    DATE_VAL <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY
    cd.DATE_VAL
'
```

There is an in depth example here: [SQL Server Undocumented Stored Procedures sp_MSforeachtable and sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm)

Comment: I never knew about that system procedure! saves the time making a cursor. Unfortunately the query run time is still similar to my original cursor which makes sense as i now know it's the actual SQL query that is the problem.

Comment: Also I have a few tables that need mitigating from the loop so some flexibility is required

Comment: If the problem is your query execution speed, then you probably haven't got any indexes to work with. DATE_EVERY_DAY.DATE_VAL should be indexed, but unfortunately that CAST of tn.IMPORT_DATE will never be indexed. 

Depending upon how much you are allowed to muck about with the source tables, you could create an additional column of type DATE and record the IMPORT_DATE value in there. I assume that the CAST is because the IMPORT_DATE column is a DATETIME or DATETIME2, and you need to remove the time part. If not, stick an index on all of them.

Comment: If you have tables you need to skip, depending on how many there are, you can either exclude them in the WHERE clause WHERE ''?'' NOT IN(''table1'',''table2''), or create a temporary table containing the tables to exclude, left join it and exclude based on the value from the temp table being NULL

Comment: Yeah it seems the lack of indexing isn't helping. The only reason I have to cast to a DATE is to do with the GROUP BY clause. My overall aim is to count how many records have been imported every day. There are multiple sets of records that are imported every day at different times so a GROUP BY on those DATETIMES would not give me a daily value

Comment: The answer I gave will populate your COUNT_RECORDS table, however after you have populated it, you can then keep it up to date incrementally. Is there an index on the IMPORT_DATE column?